# How can I find the version of .NET run-time programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need a solution to give me the *.NET* run-time version of both the full framework as well as the *.NET Core*.

On a machine with the following *.NET* versions:

```
Full: 4.7.2
Core: 2.1.104
```

Running:

```
RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription
```

Gives me:

```
Full: .NET Framework 4.7.2558.0
Core: .NET Core 4.6.26212.01
```

Running:

```
Environment.Version
```

Gives me:

```
Full: 4.0.30319.42000
Core: 4.0.30319.42000
```

How can I accurately get the run-time versions across different platforms knowing that the registry option is not available outside *Windows*.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the run-time versions across different platforms"? Your code accurately gives you the .NET versions and ```RuntimeInformation.OSDescription``` will give you the OS. What do you mean by the "registry option"? Do you want to peek a the registry if you are in windows?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: By "run-time version" you do mean CLR version, right?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I believe the _CLR_ version is what `Environment.Version` returns but it's returning the same version on both core and the full framework. In this instance what I am after is the _framework_ version. The docs seems to make things even more confusing, the link I have posted in my comment above refers to getting the framework version and then interpreting the version based on the returned _CLR_ version. But it doesn't talk about _.NET Core_.

Comment: You see the same CLR version in the `Environment.Version` output because as of .NET Framework 4.6 both Framework and Core run on the .NET Standard 2.0-compliant CLR: they really are the same (which doesn't answer your real question, of course).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ideally you should not care too much about the version of .NET you are running on. There are better
techniques like using reflection to check for features or by using
[self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained)
to completely control the version of .NET included with your application.

Library authors targeting .NET Standard however often need to customize behavior depending on which
type of .NET try are running on.

### Detecting the version of modern .NET

If you are targeting .NET Core 3.0 or later (and to be clear, this also applies if you are targeting .NET 5 and later),
the answer is very simple:
[`Environment.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.version?view=net-8.0#system-environment-version)
returns the version of the .NET runtime and
[`RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.frameworkdescription?view=net-8.0#system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation-frameworkdescription)
returns a textual description like `.NET Core 3.1.32` or `.NET 7.0.12`. See
[this breaking change notice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.0#apis-that-report-version-now-report-product-and-not-file-version)
that describes this behavior.

If you are targeting earlier versions of .NET Core or the .NET Framework, the story is more complicated.

### Detecting different types of .NET

If you merely want to differentiate between .NET Framework and .NET (nee .NET Core), you can use the
[`RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.frameworkdescription?view=net-8.0#system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation-frameworkdescription).
For example, if you are just trying to figure out whether your should dynamically load an assembly for
.NET or .NET Framework, this property should be enough. It exists on every version of .NET Core (and .NET),
so if the property does not exist your are probably running on an older version of .NET Framework.

You can do something like this:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Assembly a;
if (RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription.StartsWith(".NET Framework"))
{
    a = Assembly.LoadFile("netfx/MyAssembly.dll");
}
else
{
    a = Assembly.LoadFile("netcore/MyAssembly.dll");
}
```

### Older frameworks

If you are running on .NET Framework and really need to know version, you will have to use the
[registry method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed).
Note that .NET Framework looks are the target framework of your application and changes its behavior
to preserve backwards compatibility, so there are limits to this approach.

If you are trying to detect the exact version of .NET Core prior to 3.0, there are not any good answers
that I know of. If you are in a
[framework-dependant application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-framework-dependent),
you can look at location of system assembly and parse out a version from. For example, this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
```

prints this when running on my machine:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.8\System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

You can see the version in the file path, but I don't think this is a reliable way to detect the version.
For example, this would not work in a self-contained .NET Core app.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, the .NET Core reflection approach _might_ work with .NET Framework ... I didn't think to try it. But I think long-term there is actually a third (unified) method being planned (which doesn't work at all today) -- you can find it mentioned somewhere on a cross-reference from those links.

Comment: The reflection approach on the full fat framework returns `null` for the `TargetFrameworkAttribute`, so can't be used there.

Comment: I _think_ that's actually one of the bug reports you'll run across if you chase all those github cross-references -- which probably means in the long term reflection will support whatever other APIs they add. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: For .NET Framework the approach will return which .NET Framework does the application 'target', and not what it is installed on the system.

Comment: (missed the 5 minute window to update the above comment) The same is true for .NET Core -- it will tell you the version of the runtime it was targeted to run on. If you want to know the actual runtime version you are running on, take a look at the solution I suggested.

Comment: As of the latest .NET Core 3.0 RC1 release, it is reported that the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription` property will return the proper version of the current .NET runtime that the assembly is running on. Also the `System.Environment.Version` property should also work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Chezzwizz, I have updated the answer with these new API behaviors. To the author, I just realized that this was originally your answer, not mine, so sorry for replacing it entirely without consulting you ^_^ . Feel free to revert, however I think this answer now better reflects the version detection techniques available in .NET since the question was originally answered.

Comment: @Austin No big deal, it isn't like I'm getting royalties or something. :)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to know which version of .NET Framework is installed on a machine you should use the documented 'Release Key' Registry Key. That key is registered in the system when .NET Framework is installed.

This is publicly documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

You have to write the code that will read that registry key and map it to an actual .NET Framework version. Here is code that does that for .NET Framework versions betwee 4.5 and 4.7.1. You can further customize that as you need to. (from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/CoreFx.Private.TestUtilities/src/System/PlatformDetection.NetFx.cs#L33)

```
    private static Version GetFrameworkVersion()
    {
        using (RegistryKey ndpKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"))
        {
            if (ndpKey != null)
            {
                int value = (int)(ndpKey.GetValue("Release") ?? 0);
                if (value >= 528040) 
                    return new Version(4, 8, 0);

                if (value >= 461808) 
                    return new Version(4, 7, 2);

                if (value >= 461308)
                    return new Version(4, 7, 1);

                if (value >= 460798)
                    return new Version(4, 7, 0);

                if (value >= 394802)
                    return new Version(4, 6, 2);

                if (value >= 394254)
                    return new Version(4, 6, 1);

                if (value >= 393295)
                    return new Version(4, 6, 0);

                if (value >= 379893)
                    return new Version(4, 5, 2);

                if (value >= 378675)
                    return new Version(4, 5, 1);

                if (value >= 378389)
                    return new Version(4, 5, 0);

                throw new NotSupportedException($"No 4.5 or later framework version detected, framework key value: {value}");
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException(@"No registry key found under 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' to determine running framework version");
        }
    }
```

I know you said that you don't want to use the registry, however I recommend you use the registry path if you are running on .NET Framework (you can detect that by looking at the path where assembly containing `System.Object` is loaded from) as that is the recommended and supported way (we use the same inside the .NET Runtime when we need to check what version is installed on a machine).

For .NET Core there isn't a registry key you can check. However, you can use the location of the assembly that contains `System.Object` to identify the version on which your code is running on.

```
    public static Version GetVersion()
    {
        string runtimePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
        // Making the assumption that the path looks like this
        // C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.6
        string version = runtimePath.Substring(runtimePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

        return new Version(version);
    }
```

Comment: Interesting but unfortunately does not work with self-contained apps. upvoted regardless.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, for selfcontained apps this will not work. But for those you know the runtime at development time and that won’t change when you deploy the app.

Comment: value for 4.7.2 = 461808 so if (value >= 461808) return new Version (4, 7, 2);

Comment: @MoonWaxing Modified according to your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, for Inno Setup, I needed to find out if NET Core was installed and if so which version? Using the registry is not the way. For this reason, I reading console outputs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Detect installed NET Core version (major).
    /// The method for .NET Framework applications and library when you need to know are the NETCore application running is possible 
    /// For NETCore application simple use Environment.Version Property
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// NET Core version or error code:
    /// -1: some exception
    /// -2: not installed or wrong dotnet prompt
    /// -3: access file system problems
    /// </returns>
    [DllExport("GetNETCoreVersion", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static int GetNETCoreVersion()
    {
        try
        {
            //we need create and run .cmd file to make console output redirection to file with using ">" operator (OLD GOOD MS DOS)
            string cmdFileName = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".cmd";
            string versionFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

            //like: cmd dotnet --version with console output redirection to file "versionFileName"
            //full command id: cmd dotnet --version >> "versionFileName"                
            File.WriteAllText(cmdFileName, "dotnet --version > " + versionFileName);

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(cmdFileName),
                FileName = cmdFileName
            };

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
            {
                StartInfo = startInfo
            };
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            //after success dotnet --version >> "tempFileName", the "tempFileName" file must be exists and contains NET Core version 
            if (File.Exists(versionFileName))
            {
                string versionsinfo = File.ReadAllText(versionFileName);
                File.Delete(versionsinfo);
                //only major version is interested
                versionsinfo = versionsinfo.Substring(0, versionsinfo.IndexOf("."));
                int version = -2;
                int.TryParse(versionsinfo, out version);
                return version;
            }
            return -3;
        }
        catch
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way is:

> string installedVersion =
> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.TargetFrameworkName; //for .NET Framework:
>
> string installedVersion =
> Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetCustomAttribute()?.FrameworkName; //for .NET Core:

But to call the "TargetFrameworkName" method, it is necessary to have at least version 4.5 installed. So, it is recommended to use the alternative way in an older version that has been tested in my case:

> Version installedVersion = Environment.Version;