# No exception/warning if running application targeted 4.6.0 on 4.5.0 framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, .net-framework-version

Does anybody know how to fix such behavior?

I've created simple application(to retest if it reproducible with any .net app) targeted 4.6.0, and run it on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 (vms) which has 4.5.2(or 4.5.0) framework installed as latest. 
issue is that no error or warning showing when app is started (you can see such process, but some time later process disappears). If you run same app on framework 3.5, you will see next standard warning:[image]. srry it was french iso, but it should be clear what do i mean.

I need to show user some warning if required framework missing, because we re-targeting framework to latest.

app.config contains next line:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
```

UPDATE:
This is just example of simple app 4.6.0 which i used as test of warning. App uses Subject from System.Reactive, which targets 4.6.0

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private Subject<int> sbj = new Subject<int>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(_=>test());
        sbj.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(onNext);
    }

    private void onNext(int v)
    {
        this.myBox.Text =v.ToString();
    }

    private void test()
    {
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100))
        {
            sbj.OnNext(i);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You application won't fail until it tries to use a method or class explicitly tied to version 4.6.

If you want it to fail early, just check the version of the .net framework version installed at application startup. See this question for how to do that.

[How can I find the version of .NET run-time programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750769/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-net-run-time-programmatically)

Comment: Link didn't help, also i have code which uses functionality from 4.6. i'll update question with example of code

Comment: and i also tried to add: string ver = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.TargetFrameworkName; didn't affect, process still started, and then dies silently