# How to find the .NET Core Desktop Runtime is installed in a windows machine

Tags: windows, .net-core, registry, regedit

Is there any registry key to determine whether a windows machine has the  .NET Core Desktop Runtime installed programmatically (e.x through c#)?
I can see the registry is getting the following key when I install the .net core runtime
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.NETCore.App<version>

This key is not specific to .NET Core Desktop Runtime what I want to know explicitly the .NET Core Desktop Runtime.
I am modifying an existing installation setup for a WPF application and there I need to check the availability of .NET Core Desktop Runtime and if not installed then have to go and install. The tool that I am usinig to create the installation setup has the facility to check a particular registry key and also can download and run any exe (may be the .net desktop runtime). Please help

Answer (score 3):

try this paths to find versions:

```
'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.**WindowsDesktop**.App';

'SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\sharedfx\Microsoft.**WindowsDesktop**.App';
```

Comment: Not in my case; on a system where .NET Core and Windows Desktop Runtimes are both installed, both registry settings are listed under 'Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.NETCore.App'.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the control panel, you can see the available .Net Runtime download.

[image: ControlPanel]

Comment: thanks for tip. Do you have any idea how we can determine the available runtime in a windows system programmatically? I think I have missed one important part in the question that is I need to check this programmatically. I will update the question

Comment: @Nlr maybe this is what you're looking for then https://stackoverflow.com/a/49754978/9936356

Answer (score 0):

You can use power shell commands:

```
dotnet --list-runtimes 
dotnet --list-sdks
dotnet --info
```